# Smoke along a motion Path

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm interested in recreating Reaper's smoke transformations from the Overwatch Shorts. In the video below, they showcase how they achieved this. I'd like to know if it is achievable in Blender:

[BlizzCon 2016 Overwatch Animated Short | Reaper's Smoke Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVnNNeQhKRA)

Comment: I would suggest looking at particles and using [point density](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJietAeINTc).

Answer (score 1):

Particles can be used to emit smoke, and I've seen something quite similar to what you posted.

The current version of Blender allows a lot of particle tricks, like particles fighting flocking etc..

It might take Blender a bit more time to render, but smoke is pretty good from blender. [Here is Death-Eater (*Harry Potter* effect)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOGJg7wfx54) that's quite close to what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Is there any way to make that effect a little more thick? Also, thanks for the answer!

Comment: To change thickness of smoke alter the material of the volumetric object. But to get heavier smoke you have to change the physics of the volume. Mostly subdivision.

Comment: or change the shader